# Xamarin Form Camera and Gallery on Single Tap

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Is there any sample or example just tap on button and open camera and Gallery button on same page

**Exp:** WhatsApp or Facebook camera.
[image]

Comment: Can you show us an image of what you are looking for

Comment: Please see example image,  on the same view I can click image gallery or capture photo.

Comment: Well If you want to do this in Xamarin forms there is no direct way you will have to do it separately in iOS and Android using native API's, For Android you will be using Camera2

Comment: Thanks Hakim. I am looking for if anybody already created same kind of control. It will be great help.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at this in Xamarin.iOS [ImagePicker-xamarin-ios](https://github.com/Softeq/ImagePicker-xamarin-ios).

Comment: Wow image picker is great.